# Building a GUI using GridBagLayout (Java)

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I am trying to build a GUI for a little Java game using a GridBagLayout. Finally it should look like this:

[image: Box Drawing]

This is my code:

```
    private GridBagConstraints c;

    ...

    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 0;
    c.weightx = 0;
    add(playButton, c);

    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 1;
    c.weightx = 0;
    add(optionsButton, c);

    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 2;
    c.weightx = 0;
    add(manualButton, c);

    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 3;
    c.weightx = 0;
    add(exitButton, c); 

    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 4;
    c.weightx = 1;      
    c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.SOUTHWEST;
    add(creditsButton, c);

    c.gridx = 2;
    c.gridy = 4;
    c.weightx = 1;
    c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.SOUTHEAST;
    add(legalNoticeButton, c);
```

At the moment it looks like this:

[image: Button Layout]

My question is who I can set the two buttons to the bottom without setting the four other bottoms to the top?

Comment: You could try using a BorderLayout, with the Game buttons in a JPanel in the Center position, the bottom buttons in a JPanel in the South position, and dummy JPanels with no content in the North, East, and West positions.

Comment: Is there no easier solution using the "weighty" and "anchor" attributes?

Comment: Another alternative would be to create a 3 column by 8 row matrix, using dummy JLabels with blank text to fill in the spots where you don't want JButtons.

Comment: Is there no solution without dummies?

Comment: `Is there no easier solution` - the easier solution is to use the BorderLayout as described. You can't center the buttons in the middle if you have other components on the same panel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this is more or less @Gilbert Le Blanc explained (with minor differences):

Basically use another panel to move your two buttons to the south and spread them to WEST and EAST:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class TestGridBagLayout {

    protected void initUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("test");
        final JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel();
        centerPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        JButton playButton = new JButton("Play");
        JButton optionsButton = new JButton("Options");
        JButton manualButton = new JButton("Manual");
        JButton exitButton = new JButton("Exit");
        JButton creditsButton = new JButton("Credits");
        JButton legalNoticeButton = new JButton("Legal");
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
        centerPanel.add(playButton, c);
        centerPanel.add(optionsButton, c);
        centerPanel.add(manualButton, c);
        centerPanel.add(exitButton, c);

        JPanel bottomPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        bottomPanel.add(creditsButton, BorderLayout.WEST);
        // Filler component that avoids having the bottom panel too small
        bottomPanel.add(new JComponent() {
            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(centerPanel.getPreferredSize().width, 0);
            }
        });
        bottomPanel.add(legalNoticeButton, BorderLayout.EAST);
        frame.add(centerPanel);
        frame.add(bottomPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setMinimumSize(frame.getPreferredSize());
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException,
            UnsupportedLookAndFeelException {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new TestGridBagLayout().initUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```